# Crystal report that auto-emails to vendors in Parameter

Tags: email, crystal-reports, oracle-sqldeveloper

This is a little bit of a stretch, but we're trying to convert old reports in an increasingly unstable Access Database and I have a question.
Here's what the report does in Access currently:

1. The user gets prompted for one of our many Suppliers in a drop down style list
2. Once the supplier is entered, that Suppliers list of parts will be populated
3. The report then pulls an email address from our system (IFS) and emails the list that has been populated to the email in our files.

We've made a SQL Query that will pull in the information that we need to replicate the report, but we're at a sort of cross-roads with how to get it to automatically go through the list of Suppliers that are in the Parameters and send off the email to them all automatically.

Would there be an easier way to do this in Crystal Reports (2011) besides automating the report and selecting all the parameters manually or in Oracle SQL Developer through maybe a WHILE LOOP?

Thanks in advance, and if you need any more information, I'll try and clarify!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a data driven report ( publication). You will run a query to retrieve the list if suppliers and their emails then run a report for each record returned by the query. Let say you have a report , which accepts a parameter SupplierID and the query returns data like this

```
SupplierID   SupplierEmail
```

ID=1                email=supplierA@mail.com

ID=2                email=supplierB@mail.com

ID=3                email=supplierC@mail.com

The software will get row #1 and will use ID=1, as a parameter for Suppliers report, will export the report and will send the exported file to supplierA@mail.com. Then it will move to the next row and will use ID=2 as a parameter for the next run of the same report, export it and send it to supplierB@mail.com. The same will happen for row #3.  You can check also this video, which demonstrates the proces: http://www.r-tag.com/Pages/Preview_CreateBatchJob.aspx .
Because the values for report parameters, emails etc are returned by the query this approach is known as data driven report ( publication).

Data driven publications are available in SSRS if you own SQLServer Enterprise license. There are other types of software who support them. The sample video above is from R-Tag, which could be useful too and supports SSRS, Crystal reports and SQL Ad-hoc queries. If you use Ad-hoc query you can export suppliers data to Excel without creating a special report.